# Leitmotifs in "revival era" Doctor Who

Tags: soundtrack, doctor-who

In the "revival era" (2005-) Doctor Who, there are a number of leitmotifs assigned to various characters and adversaries, typically recognizable within a few bars/seconds, of which I know:

- Clara Oswald (Clara's theme)
- Martha Jones
- The Cybermen
- The Daleks (at least in some appearances)
- Bad Wolf (not exactly a character)

These themes have often been played to foreshadow the appearance of the character/adversary, hence the distinctiveness of each theme, recognizable almost instantly.

There are other themes associated with the Doctor such as when he saves the day, but that's outside the scope of my question.

When Donna reappears in "Partners in Crime", the incidental music seems more about setting a comedic tone than representing a character, so I don't see it as a character leitmotif.

My question is whether all the Doctor's companions (Rose, Donna, Amy) were given their own "signature" leitmotifs or if it was only done in a few cases.

Comment: Each of those characters (Amy, Donna, Rose) had their own theme - and each have fairly recognisable and extractable signatures.